# Apache <Directory /> setting affecting <Location /server-status>

Tags: apache-2.4

After studying the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html) I wouldn't expect directives in a `<Directory>` container affect non-filesystem URLs like `/server-status` in the following (full) config:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir /var/run/apache2
PidFile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
User www-data
Group www-data
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Listen 80

LoadModule mpm_worker_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule authz_core_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule     status_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
</Location>

<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Still, if I run Apache/2.4.25 on Debian stretch with this config like

```
# apache2 -f demo.conf -X
```

I get

```
$ curl --head http://localhost/server-status
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

while if I replace `denied` in the above config with `granted`, I get

```
curl --head http://localhost/server-status
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

In other words, the `Require` directive in the `<Directory />` block does affect the reachability of this URL. Which part of the documentation explains this?

Answer (score 0):

You only set a **single access control**:

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

The section on [directive merging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging) explains that `Directory` sections get applied first, before directives in `Location` sections, regardless of how they are ordered in your httpd.conf.

The behaviour you then see is explained in the [`AuthMerging`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#authmerging) Directive:

> When authorization is enabled, it is normally *inherited by each subsequent configuration section*, ***unless*** a different set of authorization directives is specified. This is the default action...

You don't set any additional access controls in  the `<Location /server-status>` configuration section that would override the only access control you did set, the `Require all denied` and that is the access control that gets inherited by the mod-status module in the /server-status webspace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `AuthMerging` directive, I haven't encountered it yet. My problem with your explanation is that merging is supposed to happen amongst applicable sections only, and I don't see why `<Directory />` would apply to the `/server-status` URL, which does not address a filesystem object.

Comment: @FerencWágner what HBrujin is trying to tell you is all you need to do is `Require all granted` added in the location section.

Answer (score 0):

As @ezra-s emphasized on IRC, even for purely virtual URIs (like `/server-status` in the example config in the question) Apache tries to match the leading part (`/` in this case) with the filesystem. For absolute URIs the leading `/` will always match the `DocumentRoot`, but further path components may match as well, if they happen to exist under `DocumentRoot`. We can replace the `<Location /server-status>` and `<Directory />` sections of the config in the question by the following to demonstrate this:

```
<Location /foo/server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
</Location>

<Location /bar/server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
</Location>

<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>

# The /var/www/html/foo directory exists, this makes /foo/server-status accessible:
<Directory /var/www/html/foo>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# The /var/www/html/bar directory does not exist, this does not make /bar/server-status accessible:
<Directory /var/www/html/bar>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# But this helps regardless (through another means):
<Location /bar>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

So this is how virtual locations get affected by `<Directory>` blocks.